# Gatsby GDPR Cookie Banner how to implement multiple cookies + disable tracking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, graphql, gatsby

So I set up a basic cookie banner following the `gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies` plugin and I used `react-cookie-consent` but it only shows a simple `we use cookies on our website` with an accept button.

1. How do I pass in both `google analytics` and `google tag manager` in my cookieconsent component? The docs only show one cookieName and I don't know how to add more than just the google analytics?
2. Also, how do I check if it actually disables cookie tracking?

I added the plugin to my `gatsby-config.js`

```
  {
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`,
  options: {
    googleAnalytics: {
      trackingId: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
      cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', // default
      anonymize: true, // default
      allowAdFeatures: false // default
    },
    googleTagManager: {
      trackingId: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_TRACKING_ID', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
      cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-google-tagmanager', // default
      dataLayerName: 'dataLayer', // default
    },
    facebookPixel: {
      pixelId: 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
      cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-facebook-pixel', // default
    },
    // defines the environments where the tracking should be available  - default is ["production"]
    environments: ['production', 'development']
  },
},
```

Then I added the Cookie Banner to my layout.js

```
      <CookieConsent
    location="bottom"
    buttonText="Accept"
    declineButtonText="Decline"
    cookieName="gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics"
  >
    This website uses cookies to enhance the user experience.
  </CookieConsent>
```

Plus the cookie only tracks `gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics` but i need it to track `gatsby-gdpr-google-tagmanager` as well

Answer (score 0):

Both questions have the same answer: you have to initialize the tracking once the user has clicked the "Accept" button. That will untrack everything until the user accepts the consent. To [start tracking](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/#initialize-and-track) when the user accepts it:

```
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router" // this helps tracking the location
import { initializeAndTrack } from 'gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies'
```

And inside your accept function (`onAccept`):

```
initializeAndTrack(location)
```

In addition, according to the documentation of the [`react-cookie-consent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie-consent) package, you have exposed an `onDecline` event that is triggered when the user rejects the GDPR policy. To allow it, you must add the `enableDeclineButton` property.

```
<CookieConsent
  enableDeclineButton
  onDecline={() => {
    alert("nay!");
  }}
></CookieConsent>
```

You can set a parameter, local storage, or another cookie there.

Your final code should look like:

```
<CookieConsent
  enableDeclineButton
  onDecline={() => {
    alert("nay!"); // your stuff here
  }} 
  onAccept={() => {
      initializeAndTrack(location)
  }}
  location="bottom"
  buttonText="Accept"
  declineButtonText="Decline"
  cookieName="gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics"> 
  This website uses cookies to enhance the user experience.
</CookieConsent>
```

Comment: how do I check if it is actually working? Also, my cookies only show google analytics in the cookies and for cookieName I can't add both google analytics & google tag manager?

Comment: You shouldn't add GTM because GTM does not store cookies that are tracking stuff. Tools enabled via GTM store cookies.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can import Cookies (from js-cookie) and set cookies manually with the onAccept function.

Something like this

```
import CookieConsent, { Cookies } from "react-cookie-consent";

<CookieConsent
  location="bottom"
  buttonText="Accept"
  declineButtonText="Decline"
  cookieName="gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics"
  onAccept={() => {
    Cookies.set("gatsby-gdpr-google-tagmanager", true)
  }}
>
This site uses cookies ...
</CookieConsent>
```